# sxa storefront empty?

Tags: sxa, sitecore-commerce, deployment

I have installed Sitecore commerce 9 using a deploy script. The installation seem to have gone ok.

Problem is when i enter the page sxa.storefront.com - Is it supposed to an empty page with the text [no catalog data available]

And I am not able to rerun the deploy script. When I do I enter an error message stating:

```
[------------------------------------------- InstallModule : InstallModule -------------------------------------------]
Installing module:  Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6 rev. 180103 for 9.0.zip
http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6 rev. 180103 f
or 9.0.zip
VERBOSE: GET http://sxa.storefront.com/SiteUtilityPages/InstallModules.aspx?modules=Sitecore Experience Accelerator 1.6
 rev. 180103 for 9.0.zip with 0-byte payload
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallItem(BehaviourOptions installOptions, Item targetItem, ItemReference
item, XmlVersionParser parser, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +386
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference,
XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +375
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\Program
Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\SitecoreInstallFramework\1.2.0\Public\Install-SitecoreConfiguration.ps1:258 char:21
+                     & $entry.Task.Command @paramSet | Out-Default
+                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:05:55
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\SXAStorefront.Framework.180508.log
Install-SitecoreConfiguration :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallItem(BehaviourOptions installOptions, Item targetItem, ItemReference
item, XmlVersionParser parser, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +386
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference,
XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +375
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Deploy-Sitecore-Commerce.ps1:81 char:2
+     Install-SitecoreConfiguration @params -Verbose
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Install-SitecoreConfiguration

[TIME] 00:09:13
Transcript stopped, output file is C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Master_SingleServer.180508.log
Invoke-RestMethod :

        One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.


         body {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size: .7em;color:black;}
         p {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         b {font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:bold;color:black;margin-top: -5px}
         H1 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:18pt;color:red }
         H2 { font-family:"Verdana";font-weight:normal;font-size:14pt;color:maroon }
         pre {font-family:"Consolas","Lucida Console",Monospace;font-size:11pt;margin:0;padding:0.5em;line-height:14pt}
         .marker {font-weight: bold; color: black;text-decoration: none;}
         .version {color: gray;}
         .error {margin-bottom: 10px;}
         .expandable { text-decoration:underline; font-weight:bold; color:navy; cursor:hand; }
         @media screen and (max-width: 639px) {
          pre { width: 440px; overflow: auto; white-space: pre-wrap; word-wrap: break-word; }
         }
         @media screen and (max-width: 479px) {
          pre { width: 280px; }
         }



            Server Error in '/' Application.
             One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.

             Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please
review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

             Exception Details: System.AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the
subscribers to the 'item:saved' event.
            Source Error:




Line 52:         context.AddAspect&lt;IFileInstallerEvents&gt;(events);
Line 53:
Line 54:         new Installer().InstallPackage(package, context);
Line 55:
Line 56:         // Execute Post Step




             Source File:  c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx &nbsp;&nbsp; Line:  54

            Stack Trace:




[AggregateException: One or more exceptions occurred while processing the subscribers to the &#39;item:saved&#39;
event.]
   Sitecore.Events.EventSubscribers.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters, EventResult result) +1849
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseEvent(String eventName, Object[] parameters) +390
   Sitecore.Events.Event.RaiseItemSaved(Object sender, ItemSavedEventArgs args) +294
   System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e) +0
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.RaiseEvent(EventHandler`1 handlers, Func`2 argsCreator) +129
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.EngineCommand`2.Execute() +202
   Sitecore.Data.Engines.DataEngine.SaveItem(Item item) +229
   Sitecore.Pipelines.ItemProvider.SaveItem.TriggerDataEngine.Process(SaveItemArgs args) +98
   (Object , Object[] ) +74
   Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run(PipelineArgs args) +469
   Sitecore.Data.Managers.DefaultItemManager.SaveItem(Item item) +127
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.AcceptChanges(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +126
   Sitecore.Data.Items.ItemEditing.EndEdit(Boolean updateStatistics, Boolean silent) +28
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallItem(BehaviourOptions installOptions, Item targetItem, ItemReference
item, XmlVersionParser parser, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +386
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.GetVersionInstallMode(PackageEntry entry, ItemReference reference,
XmlVersionParser parser, ItemInstallerContext context, Boolean&amp; removeVersions) +375
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.InstallEntry(PackageEntry entry) +1304
   Sitecore.Install.Items.ItemInstaller.Flush() +156
   Sitecore.Install.Framework.SinkDispatcher.Flush() +102
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Flush() +228
   Sitecore.Install.Zip.PackageReader.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +565
   Sitecore.Install.Utils.EntrySorter.Populate(ISink`1 sink) +80
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, Boolean registerInstallation, ISource`1 source,
IProcessingContext context) +444
   Sitecore.Install.Installer.InstallPackage(String path, IProcessingContext context) +72
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Install(String package) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:54
   ASP.siteutilitypages_installmodules_aspx.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
c:\inetpub\wwwroot\sc90.local\SiteUtilityPages\InstallModules.aspx:36
   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +103
   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +68
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
+1381





            Version Information:&nbsp;Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.7.2633.0


At C:\deploy\SIF.Sitecore.Commerce.1.1.4\Modules\SitecoreUtilityTasks\SitecoreUtilityTasks.psm1:20 char:5
+     Invoke-RestMethod $urlInstallModules -TimeoutSec 720
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

I am not sure what this errror indicate?

Comment: Crossposting. https://community.sitecore.net/developers/f/6/t/9101